# How can I add and use(open) multiple RN apps inside the core app of React native without jumping from the core app?(without deep linking)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, frontend

How can I add and use(open) multiple RN apps inside the core app(one main app) with out jumping from the core app ?

I need to create a super-app of react native (one app), who contain all the multiple app to use inside that app in react native for both android and iOS.(without deep linking)

Comment: may I ask... why?

Comment: already I have multiple released apps so I want to merge all of the apps in to one.

Comment: You want micro-sevice ?

Comment: yes we need micro-service